# Trying to hide div class on screen size

Tags: html, css, hide

I'm trying to get an element to hide at 460px and below. 
I'm trying to hide the phone number & email at the very top in the header. 
info@locksmithsuppler.com  (909) 278-2644

I'm having trouble. Thank you for helping.
http://www.superherodigital.com/locksmithsupplier/

I have this code in place but it is not working

```
media="all"
@media (max-width: 460px)
#hide-none {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have correct syntax and information.

Use this and also when you are looking on mobile you need to make sure your meta tags are correct.

```
@media (max-width: 460px){
    #hide-none {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Your view port is important for mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
@media
```

query you have is incorrect. The correct syntax for that would be

```
@media (max-width: 460px){
    #hide-none {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

with a curly-brace for the media query and separate curly braces for the selectors inside of the query. Refer to  Cayce K for the viewport comment, it is really important.